# MP1584 5v regulator voltage drop problem

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I was debugging the [MP1584](https://www.monolithicpower.com/pub/media/document/MP1584_r1.0.pdf) module, 5v regulator circuit in the PCB.
I have attached my debug circuit below.

[image: MP1584 debug circuit]

I have completed my circuit in breadboard and PCB also, but I was connected to any load below 2A. It will produce the voltage drop and alternative output voltage.

Mp1584 specs : max 3A , i/p volt = 4.5v to 28v , my i/p volt = 12v

I need 5 V output and less than 2 A current. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you be clear about what the problem is?

Comment: my voltage was drop when I connected to any load

Comment: Did the input voltage to the regulator also drop?

Comment: The schematic photo has very poor resolution but the components seem to be against suggested values for 5V operation.